# How to display remaing instead of total pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

this works to graph the total, but is it possible to grab the remaining?

```
data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Pandas\\SANS.xlsx')
data2 = data.groupby(['Department']).count()
```

C:\Users\dbeiler\Desktop\Pandas>python PythonApplication1.py

```
   Completion Department Email
0          62      AQPSD   165
1          68        ASD   147
2           8         CO    37
3         141      ECARS   242
4          60         ED   171
5          19         EO    69
6          53        ISD   141
7          85        MLD   181
8          73       MSCD   158
9          35        OIS    94
10         34         RD    78
11         39        TTD   103
```

for example, instead of AQPSD 62, 105, i'd like 62, 103
the first column is the department name (as shown), second coloumn that is displaying results is the total number of employees (based on their email and counting the total number of emails), and the third is displaying a completion column (counting total number of employees that completed the training), based on their department

this is what the xlsx document looks like (but with 1500 rows)

Department  Email   Completion
(3 seperate columns), my current pandas line works, i just want to get the remaining, instead of total

```
Department Email Completion
MSCD    email1  
EO      email2   Complete
MLD     email3   Complete
ISD     email4   Complete
MSCD    email5  
AQPSD   email6  
ASD     email7   Complete
EO      email8  
AQPSD   email9  
ED      email10 
ASD     email11  Complete
ECARS   email12 
MLD     email13  Complete
AQPSD   email14 
ASD     email15 
AQPSD   email16  Complete
MSCD    email17
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand precisely what you're after if you included the dataset in question: the SANS.xlsx

Comment: "instead of AQPSD 62, 105": which is not what your example shows. It may be a simple typo, but please be clear</pedantic>.

Comment: Where would the 103 come from? How did you calculate that?

Comment: <pedantic>@Evert, you forgot to open with "<pedantic>".</pedantic> (But it's probably a typo for 165.)

Comment: Very unclear and no effort to make it readable -1

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to subtract the 2nd column from the 3rd column?

Comment: 103, is the difference of 65 (total completed) and 105 (total employees in that department)

Comment: @BrendenPeterson, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.groupby('Department').count().eval('Remaining = Email - Completion', inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
            Email  Completion  Remaining
Department                              
AQPSD           4           1          3
ASD             3           2          1
ECARS           1           0          1
ED              1           0          1
EO              2           1          1
ISD             1           1          0
MLD             2           2          0
MSCD            3           0          3
```

Comment: it was too easy, i wish i knew i could easiy add eval at the end :)

Comment: [eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas-dataframe-eval)  See API docs.